# Why is there no option to print from Safari on iOS?

Tags: ios, safari, printing

For quite some time (although I don't know when this began), I've been dumbfounded by the fact that I can't find any option for printing from Sfaari. If I go into the Share sheet and look at the "Actions" list, it isn't there. If I click on "Edit Actions…", it's nowhere to be found.

There is a Print option in other apps, such as Mail.

I do have an available AirPrint printer on my network, but I think there would still be a Print option even if I didn't have one.

How can I troubleshoot iOS share when it’s missing print from mobile Safari on iOS 15?

Comment: FWIW, I have the print option (on iOS 15.2.1): https://imgur.com/a/KhbOdpa . Does this only happen for you on certain websites?

Comment: No. Isn't that weird? Seems like I need some sort of Safari reset. Could extensions interfere with this?

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Safari > "Clear History and Website Data" seems to have fixed the problem!